# In any way, is it acceptable for the first letter of each word in a web article's title to be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization

We've all seen this at some stage on the internet, and are seeing it more and more recently.

Capitalizing is applied to the first letter of each word in a title :

> This Is The Title Of The Article

These are generally celebrity stories or ads for diets or other gibberish.

Is this specifically an online practice to grab our attention in some way?

Is it acceptable in any other format?

Comment: The Web Is The Wild West Where You Can Do Whatever You Want.

Comment: ...but [this website](http://titlecapitalization.com/) says *The Web Is **the** Wild West Where You Can Do Whatever You Want* (they don't think the second ***the*** should be capitalised).

Comment: It is traditional for "titles" of "major works" (or some term to that effect) to have all "significant" words capitalized.  There are written rules for this in most books of English guidelines, and relatively little argument over them.  (Generally these rules say one should not capitalize "minor" words such as "of" and "the".)  Whether a web article is "major work" is of course a good question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Cheater.

Comment: One thing to consider is that websites use CSS to style pages, and CSS includes `text-transform: capitalize` which will automatically capitalize every word in the targeted section. This is often applied to title tags/areas to ensure that everything is consistent.

Comment: @Robusto: Absolutely! When I first began to build up an mp3 music library nearly 20 years ago, I used to waste a lot of time and effort capitalising album and track names. But since I started using Foobar2000 to manage the library, I just let their built-in file move/rename routine handle all that. Okay, it's pretty dumb (it just capitalises *every* word, even **A**) - but it's *so* easy to use that I've come to accept it's not worth sweating the small stuff.

Comment: @VampDuc _CSS includes text-transform: capitalize_... Do you understand how CSS works? Every rule isn't applied to every element constantly. And _capitalize_ would capitalize every character, not just the first letter.

Comment: @Daft ...ummm, okay. `text-transform: uppercase` makes every letter capital. `text-transform: capitalize` makes the first letter of each word capital ([W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp), if you don't believe me). And no, every rule isn't applied to every element constantly, but the question was regarding titles, which are often in **title tags**. It's very easy to apply capitalization (or uppercase, lowercase, what have you) to a title tag.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you see is simply the effect of word-processing programs that aren't sophisticated enough to manage the shifting ways in which traditional guidelines for initial-capping titles work. Rather than trying to build a program that can determine the appropriateness of capitalization in specific instances—such as when a "the" immediately following a colon or an em dash in a title, or when "in" in a particular instance is used as an adverb or an adjective or a noun, rather than as a preposition—designers of word-processing programs provide only the relatively crude option of adding an initial cap to every word in a highlighted string.

Thus, in Microsoft Word, if you highlight the words

> it is a big day if you are a bug in the rug

and choose *Format* --> *Change Case...* --> *Title Case*, what you get isn't title case at all; it's Every Word Initial-Capped Case:

> It Is A Big Day If You Are A Bug In The Rug

There is no right or wrong about the treatment: It's merely the result of a word-processing program performing a very simply case conversion exactly as it was designed to do. My only criticism of the operation is that Microsoft calls the result "Title Case" (which it manifestly is not, at least as that term has been used in publishing for many years) rather than "Initial Caps" (which it clearly is).

Whether the approach is acceptable is a question to be determined by general usage and by house style. But I'm pretty sure that the proliferation of online article titles with every word initial-capped is not part of a carefully devised plan to gain the attention of Website visitors; an all-caps format is likelier to achieve that result. Instead, I suspect, it is due mainly to thousands of authors and editors choosing "Title Case" in Word as the format to use for their titles, and letting it go at that.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is totally acceptable. As Robusto mentioned in a comment, the internet is where you can do what you want.

From a grammatical point of view, it is my understanding that in British English news sites will often write titles in sentence form, e.g. `English deemed more important than maths`, whilst American English favours the more traditional "title" form, e.g. `English Deemed More Important Than Maths`.

Another thing to note is that if you do choose to use the title style, and you want to be strictly grammatical, there are some words (like "the" and "a") which in most cases should not be capitalised. But again, this is up to you, much like song titles are up to artists - some artists will opt for a capital "A" whereas others will opt for a lowercase "A".

Comment: I'm referring to titles in which every word is capitalized, including articles like _a, if,_ and _the_.

Comment: Of course, an American title wouldn't say "maths," regardless of capitalization. ;)

Comment: It's an interesting point that, isn't it? To me it makes more sense with an "S" because it abbreviates a plural noun (mathematics).

Comment: But "mathematics" is used as a singular noun, just like "politics" and "news." At least it is in the U.S. For example, we would say "Math is easy for me." Would Brits say "Maths is easy for me" or "Maths are easy for me?"

Comment: @Nicole: I think most Brits would say the final ***s*** on ***maths*** simply reflects the fact that we abbreviate the full word by removing the ***-ematic-*** bit from the middle. Would "verbose" Americans say "Mathematics are easy for me" just because of the ***s**?*

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think it would be viewed as a singular noun that ends in "s," like "economics." Although I think some dictionaries list "mathematics" as being both singular and plural.